# Is there a way to build ZFS for the linux-virt kernel on Alpine?

Tags: alpine-linux, zfs

I want to run ZFS inside of a virtual machine using Alpine Linux. The `linux-virt` kernel is much smaller and does not have the 200+MB of firmware files listed as dependencies, so that is the kernel I selected for the VM. However, I now find that there is no `zfs-virt` package, only `zfs-vanilla` which installs the vanilla kernel and all the firmware as dependencies.

Is there a `zfs-virt` package available in perhaps a third party repository? If not, I am not against building the package myself, but I'm relatively new to Alpine so have not yet figured out how its build system works nor if it is possible to build against an already-compiled kernel (in my own past experience, the only way I've successfully built kernel modules is using the source tree of the target kernel)

Answer (score 0):

Just copy paste latest zfx-lts to [zfs-virt](https://github.com/wenerme/repository/blob/master/alpine/v3.11/aports/main/zfs-virt/APKBUILD), then `abuild checksum` and `abuild -r`. There is a prebuild package in [my repository](https://github.com/wenerme/repository).

Install by

```sh
(cd /etc/apk/keys; sudo curl -LO https://repo.wener.me/alpine/wenermail@gmail.com-5dc8c7cd.rsa.pub )
echo https://repo.wener.me/alpine/v3.11/community | sudo tee -a /etc/apk/repositories

sudo apk add zfs-virt
```

Comment: Could you give a little more details on this? Your repo does not contain the zfs-virt package, btw.

Comment: @fdmillion [this](https://github.com/wenerme/repository/blob/master/alpine/v3.11/main/x86_64/zfs-virt-5.4.12-r1.apk) is prebuild zfs-virt for 3.11, I also push to upstream [here](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/merge_requests/3838). Use a prebuild zfs-virt or build against a virt kernel alpine.